# Java - Handle serialization only in superclass

Tags: java, serialization

I have a hierarchy of domain classes in my web application, which I want to make serializable. All domain classes inherit from an abstract base class. I plan to override readObject and writeObject in the abstract base class. Is there a way to make all subclasses defer to the super class for serialization, so that subclasses do not serialize any of their own fields?

I'm using [FST Serialization](https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization) - if the above is not possible in Java, is there a way to, say for example, specify a "serialization strategy" for objects of a certain type?

```
public abstract class Base implements Serializable {

    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream) 
         throws IOException {
       ...
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream) 
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
       ...
    }
}

public class Person extends Base {

   // I don't want Person class to do anything for serialization
}
```

Update: I have more than a hundred subclasses, each subclass has several fields. These classes make up the domain model in my web application. I was hoping to find an easier way to handle this other than to specify 'transient' on every field in every class.

Background: I am serializing session state in order to allow saving to a cache server. Our session object has references to domain objects. Rather than saving the entire domain object, I was hoping to only save part of the domain object, and re-construct it when the session object gets "bounced" to another server.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make all subclasses defer to the super class for serialization, so that subclasses do not serialize any of their own fields?

You can do this the same way you ask any field not to be serialized: make all of the fields in the subclass [`transient`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient) (or `static`).

But this is quite a restriction on the subclasses, and a burden on the programmer to remember to make all fields `transient`, and in some sense it makes fields in the subclasses of limited use. Consider carefully why you are trying to stop subclass fields being serialized.

Comment: I have hundreds of subclasses in my class hierarchy, plus each subclass have several fields, so it will be quite tedious.. But based on what I read so far, it seems like my only option.

Comment: Why don't you want the state of the subclasses to be serialized in the first place? If it is necessary to have the field in the class for the correct functioning of the class, why would you not need it after deserialization; and if it is not necessary, why have the field in the first place?

Comment: We use a proprietary ORM framework - all fields in our domain classes are custom "Field" classes, not java.lang.String etc. These Field classes will fetch data from the database if it does not exist in the local copy. So my initial thought was to only serialize the primary key of the domain object and rely on "lazy fetching" to populate the object when needed upon deserialization. However I realized that this assumption means that when a domain object gets deserialized in another app server, it will always represent the latest data from the db. This may not be a valid assumption after all.